# XML unit testing frameworks for MSTest

Tags: .net, xml, mstest

We need to validate the content of an xml document we generate. Are there any frameworks out there that will help make it easy to extract and validate the content of the document?

things we need to know

- contains element x
- value of element x
- element x contains attribute y with value z
- unexpected elements

It doesn't matter to much if there are no assertions, this can be done via MSTest

Comment: Do you have an xsd for the xml?

Comment: i'd prefer not to rely on xsd. we have to do some post processing at the moment to include attributes with default values. i'd rather something that can query the document. maybe just some linq to xml based helpers

Comment: The only reason I ask about the xsd is that it makes it easy to generate POCO code.  Once you've deserialized the Xml into objects verifying the contents is trivial.  The very act of deserialization would help verify the formatting.

Comment: I see, then yes that should work. can give some examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at Fluent Assertions library documentation here: https://fluentassertions.com/introduction

The section entitled "XML classes" sounds like what you're after. The code uses LINQ-to-XML underneath.

```
xDocument.Should().HaveRoot("configuration");
xDocument.Should().HaveElement("settings");

xElement.Should().HaveAttribute("age", "36");
xElement.Should().HaveElement("address");

xAttribute.Should().HaveValue("Amsterdam");
```

You can install FluentAssertions from nuget here: http://nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions

Comment: That looks exactly what i was after, i'll have to give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a tool like xsd.exe (included with VS) to generate C# entities from the XSD file you have for your XML.

Once you have the objects generated you can use an instance of [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to deserialize your XML.  If you can't deserialize your XML then you will know very quickly that you have invalid XML.

After that you should be able to fairly easily validate the contents of your XML by working with the various properties of the deserialized entities.

[Here is a good starter blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yojoshi/archive/2011/05/14/xml-serialization-and-deserialization-entity-classes-with-xsd-exe.aspx) about generating entity objects from an XSD and it shows some simple deserialization code using XmlSerializer.